# JavaFX multiple line

Tags: java

When i tried to compile code it have bug. I am trying to resolve problem one hour and i don't know this bug. Do you know how to fix it? Thanks!

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public abstract class Mainn extends Application
{
public static void main(String[] args){launch(args);

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(this.getClass.getResource("/fxml/StackPaneWindow.fxml"));
StackPane stackPane = loader.load();

Scene scene = new Scene (stackPane);

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setTitle("bang");
primaryStage.show();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see with this is that the method `start(Stage)` is inside your main function, which isn't allowed java. Close your main function before defining another function.

Comment: yyy? What do you mean? I try do it but i have more errors.

Comment: @Brade You have to actually give me the errors if you want help.